# Changing z-index on click with an image sprite?

Tags: css, z-index

If I have a navigation menu using css image sprite, is it possible to change the z-index when the link is clicked on/selected?

Comment: please provide some code with your question to get best answer (or at least an answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use CSS to change on *click* (unless you use `:active`, but that only lasts for a moment, *while* clicking). Use JavaScript instead.

Let's say your CSS looks like this:

```
#change_me {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Then you can have HTML with some inline JavaScript:

```
<div id="change_me">My z-index will change</div>
<div onclick="document.getElementById('change_me').style.zIndex='2'">
    Click Me!
</div>
```

Clicking the second `div` will change the z-index of the first (i.e. `#change_me`).

It doesn't matter what the elements are (they can be `div`'s, `span`'s, `p`'s, etc.)